# Choose default photo viewer app to open from Windows Camera

Tags: windows-10, photos, camera

*History:* I recently began getting errors when trying to open images in the default Microsoft Photos app. It turned out I'm not the only one with the problem and I'm not the only one who is unable to solve it, so I installed a different app to view photos (IrfanView). (There is an app but one can also install it as a program.)

*Problem:* When I open Windows Camera, as usual the last photo I took is shown at the bottom right of the screen. When clicking it, the photo used to be opened in Microsoft Photos. But since that app doesn't work anymore (in fact I removed it in powershell) I want Windows Camera to open the photo in a different app (IfranView). How can I do this?

I set IrfanView as the default photo viewer, but that doesn't help.

When I try to open a photo in Windows Camera, I'm asked to choose an app from the Microsoft store, but there appears to be no way to actually select an app. It just opens the store and that's it. After that, I get the error

> 0xA00F428B<FailedToLaunchPhotosApp>

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple places to set default applications in Windows 10:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `default pr` and select *Default Programs*.
- The first option to *Set your default programs* sets the handling of generic file types, e.g. images (.PNG, .JPEG, .BMP, .TIFF, etc.) would be handled by *Photo viewer*.
- Near the bottom of the dialog, select *Associate a file type or protocol with a a program* to set the specific file type used by *Windows Camera*, .JPG.
- If *IrfanView* is in the list, well and good, select it.

[image: Select JPG app]

However, it *it is not* listed, Microsoft will not allow the selection of an alternate *applications* (as opposed to the Metro [deprecated] *apps*). In order to select *IrfanView*, do the following.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open *Explorer*.
- Navigate to *This PC > Pictures > Camera Roll*.
- Right-click on a .JPG image.
- Select *Open with >*.
- If *IrfanView* is not shown, select *Choose another app*.
- Click on *Always use this app to open .JPG files*.
- Navigate to *IrfanView* and set it as the default.

[image: Select default app in Explorer]

Next time you double-click a .JPG, it should open in the correct application.

Comment: This doesn't help... The problem is not when I open image files directly in explorer,  but specifically when I open them from the Windows Camera app.

Comment: Perhaps there is a Registry setting for the image editor, though I cannot find it. You might try an alternative camera application; see https://alternativeto.net/software/contacam/

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#recommend-an-app-if-one-is-not-available-to-handle-the-uri What I want is the URI scheme `ms-photos:` to launch IrfanView. But that's too technical for me to figure out...

Comment: There is a `ms-photos` in HKCR\ but I don't know what to do with it.